# Test class for trigger

Tags: triggers, salesforce, apex

I just wrote this trigger and it seems to be working fine in dev, I need to move it into production, however, the test class I wrote passes the test but does not cover the trigger. Any help would be greatly appreciated. I am a bit green here. I know I should be inserting a contact (the account is a req field) then updating the contact field I just have no earthly clue how to do taht. Thank you

```apex
trigger PropOwned on Contact (after update) {
    for (Contact c : Trigger.new) {
        McLabs2__Ownership__c ownNew = new McLabs2__Ownership__c();
        Contact oldContact = Trigger.oldMap.get(c.id);
        if (c.One_Prop_Owned__c != oldContact.One_Prop_Owned__c && c.One_Prop_Owned__c != null) {
            ownNew.McLabs2__Contact__c = c.id;
            ownNew.McLabs2__Property__c = c.One_Prop_Owned__c;
            insert ownNew;
        }
    }
}
```

This is the test class I wrote.

```apex
@isTest
public class TestOwnership {
    static testMethod void createOwnership() {
        McLabs2__Ownership__c ownNew = new McLabs2__Ownership__c();
        ownNew.McLabs2__Contact__c = 'Michael Webb';
        ownNew.McLabs2__Property__c = '131 West 33rd Street';
        insert ownNew;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your test class just creates a `McLabs2__Ownership__c` object and inserts this object in database. As a result of this trigger on `McLabs2__Ownership__c`(if exist) will be invoked, but you have to test a trigger on `Contact` object. Thus you need to insert an account and after that update it because your contact trigger works in `after update` mode.

So, you need something like that

```apex
@isTest
private class TestOwnership {

    static testMethod void whenContactUpdatedNewOwnershipIsInserted() {
        // create contact, you have to replace 'value1' with appropriate data type
        Contact contact = new Contact(name = 'Test Contact', One_Prop_Owned__c = 'value1');
        insert contact;
        contact.One_Prop_Owned__c = 'value2'; // you have to replace value2 with appropriate data type
        update contact;
        // in this place you should has only one record of McLabs2__Ownership__c in database, because in test context real data isn't visible
        List<McLabs2__Ownership__c> ownerships = [SELECT Id, McLabs2__Contact__c, McLabs2__Property__c FROM McLabs2__Ownership__c];
        System.assertEquals(1, ownerships.size());
        System.assertEquals(contact.Id, ownerships[0].McLabs2__Contact__c);
        System.assertEquals(contact.One_Prop_Owned__c, ownerships[0].McLabs2__Property__c);
    }
}
```

Read the following articles which might be pretty useful for you:

1. [Apex Trigger best practice](https://www.salesforce.com/us/developer/docs/apexcode/Content/apex_triggers_bestpract.htm)
2. [SOQL in loop](https://developer.salesforce.com/page/Best_Practice:_Avoid_SOQL_Queries_Inside_FOR_Loops)

Comment: Thanks I have to think about this, contact.One_Prop_Owned__c is a lookup field, so when I try to put a value in it or replace it keeps saying it is an invalid id.  I will read both of those I did read the first one.  Thanks for your help

Comment: Perfect my question to you answered my question and the test class worked, 100 percent coverage!  thank you thank you thank you!